# Log who deleted a row using Change Data Capture

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, cdc

I have SQL 2014 Enterprise and have configured Change Data Capture (CDC). I have UserId columns on all of my tables. So CDC does a great job seeing who inserted and updated a row but if someone deletes a row I cant see who deleted the row (it has the previous UserId in the row). I know Oracle has this feature included in their CDC package.

Comment: An idea would be adding a `TRIGGER AFTER DELETE` to the table to log to a tracking table.

Comment: Possibly related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34079/change-data-capture-how-to-know-who-made-the-change  Aaron Bertrand's answer is (unsurprisingly) very helpful.  (Hint: CDC doesn't do this "by design."  CDC seems to have gotten the "good enough for a checkbox feature list" treatment.)

Comment: If you want tried/true way to track that kind of stuff, you can implement SQL Auditing.  CDC is simply a change tracking feature for ETL purposes, not so much auditing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger after delete which stores the userid of whoever deleted the data.  you'd want to have a table setup that has restricted access, likely to the admin, to store the information.